# How to call my unity function in my Web Project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created webGL Unity Project using .
I have one web Project which use JSP,HTML and JavaScript.

Question is:
How to call my unity function in my Web Project?

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sourcedrag : MonoBehaviour {
public static sourcedrag _instance;
public string  assetBundleURL;
public GameObject animation_;
// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
string a = "";
setAssetBundle (a);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
public void setAssetBundle (string url)
{
assetBundleURL = (url.Equals ("")) ? "put http link": url;
assatbundelcall ();
}
public void assatbundelcall()
{
string url = assetBundleURL;
Debug.Log (url);
WWW www = new WWW (url); 
StartCoroutine (WaitForReq (www));
}
IEnumerator WaitForReq (WWW www)
{
yield return www;
AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
if (www.error == null) 
{
animation_ = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAllAssets () [0];
animation_.AddComponent <ReApplyShaders> ();
Instantiate (animation_);
bundle.Unload (false);
}
else { 
Debug.Log (www.error);
}
}
}
```

Above is my code in which I need to call "setAssetBundle" method from my web project.

Comment: Please, show some code how you **tried** to do it. SO is not a training center.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a tour and visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to format your question properly and help us help you

Comment: Above is my code in which I need to call "setAssetBundle" method from my web project.